# JSF/Primefaces- Action listener on Command button not getting called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I am using JSF2.0 with Prime Faces 3.2. I have a data table with a column that has two command buttons. The second command button is rendered based on a condition. Everything works well until the data table is filtered. Once filtered the first command button without the rendered attribute calls my actionListener without any issues, whereas the second command button with the rendered attribute does not.

PS:The reason i am using f:param intead of setPropertyActionListener is because of a bug in primefaces datatable that passes the wrong row's id when filtered.

Here is my code, any insight into this issue would be great.

```
<p:column headerText="Column1" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{item.name}" sortBy="#{item.name}">
                       <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" style="float:left" />
                        <span class="inlineButton"> 
                        <p:commandButton id="selectBtn" icon="select"
                            oncomplete="dialog1.show()" actionListener="#{controller.setItem}">                         
                            <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="delBtn" icon="delete"
                        actionListener="#{controller.setItem}"
                        oncomplete="delConfirm.show()"
                        rendered="#{not empty item.id}">                            
                        <f:param name="itemId" value="#{item.id}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    </span>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: You really need buttons inside the table? I do exactly what you're trying to do but I have a toolbar just above the table. Its buttons are updated every time you select a row. If this would help I could post an example as a suggestion.

Comment: @Bento, If you have an example of your toolbar please post it. Having buttons right there in the row seemed like a nice option rather than having the user select a row and do an action. But your approach seems interesting, so please post it. Also, any idea why the buttons work without the "rendered" attribute?